# Python CSV writer freezes always at the same row

Tags: python, csv, python-3.7

I'm trying to write some rows from a table into a csv with Python3.7. The code is working fine but always freezes with the same row.

The error happens in a specific field, since eliminating that field the writer works. The value of the field in the row that fails is "L'Hospitalet de Llobregat". It's weird since other rows with that value are written. The program freezes without returning any error. Some example of rows valid are:

(280403, '28050', 'Madrid', 28, '28000010930800123    OA   001A          ')

(269432, '08905', "L'Hospitalet de Llobregat", 8, '08000760170907831         0041       ')

(280408, '09400', 'Aranda de Duero', 9, '09000020052804534         BA    ')

(280412, '28009', 'Madrid', 28, '28000010021958373         BA D          ')

The row where the writer fails is the following:

(269608, '08906', "L'Hospitalet de Llobregat", 8, '08000760015705728         EN 1       ')

```py
table = self._db_con.execute(query)
with open(path, 'w',  encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for row in table:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

EDIT:
I put a counter to skip writing that row and the program still freeze at the same point. The last row it writes is the following:
(269575, '41006', 'Sevilla', 41, '41000800023167102         002B       ')
I have no idea why the program freezes, I have tested this code with another 40 tables and it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you include a few lines/rows/records of `table` that reproduce the problem? ... [mcve]

Comment: You also need to indicate the version of Python you are using.  Python 2 would experience the same behavior you are describing when getting to a unicode character.  My guess is that the value of L'Hospitalet de Llobregat that is an issue actually has a smart quote in it that is a unicode character and not an apostrophe.

Comment: If I create a list of tuples from what you've provided, iterate through each tuple and write to a csv, it works without issue.  I'd try printing `row` make sure it is what you think it is.  But basically, I can't reproduce your error with what's provided.

Comment: @Trenton_M I put a counter to skip that row and the program still freeze at the same point. The last row it writes is the following: (269575, '41006', 'Sevilla', 41, '41000800023167102         002B       '). I will edit the answer.

Comment: I'd say use pandas.  The dataframe can be created from the query.  Once you have the dataframe you can save directly to csv with `df.to_csv('my.csv', index=False)`

Comment: @snakecharmerb The program stops advancing but no error comes out but it doesn't appear any error. I'm running on VSCode

Comment: It could be a problem with the database query; if you do `table = list(self._db_con.execute(query))` then `print(table)` does it show all the rows?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Interesting... The program freezes when I do the ```list(self._db_con.execute(query))```

Comment: So it seems there's a problem with the query, or the database connection.  Can you add the code that generates `query` to the question?  If you run the same query directly on the database, does it work?  Also, what database and driver are you using?

Comment: @snakecharmerb The query is just a simple ```SELECT fiel1, field2 ... FROM table```. The database I'm using is oracle and I'm using SQLAlchemy + Oracle Instant Client 18 to connect. If I run that query on the database it works without problem

Answer (score 0):

### Use Pandas:

- There are several functions you can try to get your data into pandas

  - [`pd.read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)
  - [`pd.read_sql_query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html)
  - [`pd.read_sql_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_table.html)
  - [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)
- Since you already have a `table`, we'll try that

#### Data:

- Given your data is already in `table`, and if it looks like the following

```py
table = [(280403, '28050', 'Madrid', 28, '28000010930800123 OA 001A '),
         (269432, '08905', "L'Hospitalet de Llobregat", 8, '08000760170907831 0041 '),
         (280408, '09400', 'Aranda de Duero', 9, '09000020052804534 BA '),
         (280412, '28009', 'Madrid', 28, '28000010021958373 BA D '),
         (269608, '08906', "L'Hospitalet de Llobregat", 8, '08000760015705728 EN 1 ')]
```

#### Code

- The previously mentioned methods, can be used to read directly from a query, see the documentation for implementation.
- [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(table)

# save to csv
df.to_csv('my_file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I have tested pandas, with other tables works fine but with this one keeps freezing

Comment: Wow!  That’s weird.  Have you tried changing the save file name, location, encoding, etc.?  I did notice there is trailing whitespace on the end of some data.  Is it possible that’s causing an issue?  I don’t really have any other suggestions.  Sorry

Comment: You could try saving only the rows after the problem spot.  In pandas, use df.loc[100:200].to_csv()

Comment: yeah, that could be an approach but I need that row. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: What happens if you try to just write the row alone?